# Root URL isn't being changed after redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have two URL's. URL A: https://www.website.com/blue/dog.htm#cat

and URL B: https://www.website.com/blue/en-us/dog.htm#cat

In the backend, the folder structure was originally **/blue/dog.htm/** but I've added a new folder, /en-us/ so now the structure for URL B is **/blue/en-us/dog.htm/**.

I can do simple redirects but I'm not sure how I would add a pathway into the middle of a URL especially when the URL A's file path no one longer exists.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.location.href = '/blue/en-us/';
</script>
</head>
```

The problem is, I've put https://www.website.com/blue/dog.htm#cat onto some external websites and now they don't redirect to the new URL.

Comment: It's not the problem of **how** to add but what is the logic of the addition. I mean, can you count that it always be in the 2nd segment of the path? Are all of the urls' paths will look something like `/category/language/item` (those just examples right?) and you want to add / remove the language segment from the path..

Comment: Instead of redirecting with javascript, you could use your webserver to redirect using regular expressions. If you're using apache httpd, you could even enforce this behavior using a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a 301 redirect via .htaccess.

See here: https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

You would define your 301 like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /seo/someoldfile.php http://www.seomoz.org
```

The `/seo/someoldfile.php` is the old URL, `http://www.seomoz.org` is the new location.

So you would do this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 https://www.website.com/blue/dog.htm#cat https://www.website.com/blue/en-us/dog.htm#cat
```

So when a user lands on Link A, they will be pushed to link B.